# PHP Writing CSV Append Mode

Tags: php, csv, paypal

I created a quick internal tool for payments within my company. I used PayPal as the processor and the notifyURL to send the IPN data.

```
    //Post Data
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$empID = $_POST['custom'];
$shirtSize = (explode(":",$_POST['item_name']));
$shirtSizeClean = $shirtSize[1];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');

//Create the array of data we are adding to the CSV
$list = array($empID,$txn_id,$payer_email,$payment_amount,$payment_status,$shirtSizeClean,$date);

//Open the CSV and write to it
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($fp, $list);
fclose($fp);
```

I noticed that all of the data hit my IPN log showing that it made it there but there is missing data on the csv it self.

With the code above, that would allow for multiple writes to the csv at the same time right? I'm wondering if payments were coming in around the same time and the file was being written to at the same time.

Could you think of any other reason the data that reason the IPN (making it to the above block of code) wouldn't end up on the CSV?

Comment: can you find out exactly which data is missing? that might have with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Full payments are missing from the data as if they didn't happen, its not just a field here and there. Only thing I can assume is that so many transactions came in around the same time that they got skipped with concurrent writes?

Comment: you can try `$fp = fopen('/file.csv', 'a') or print_r(error_get_last());` to check if all file opens are successful.